# React Native 0.61.5 version RTC Libraries Issue

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I created a project by npx react-native init-focep

React native created the project with the version 0.61.5 with ios folder.

When i open xcode of the project cannot see RTC xcode.proj files under libraries folder.

But when i create the project with the version 0.59.5 related files appears under libraries.

Empty libraries folder become an obstacle for me to build third party libs by linking them to the project with the error 'RTCDElegation.h' not found.

Can you please help me to fill libraries folder with the latest version of react-native ?

Comment: Have you run `cd ios && pod install` command ?

Comment: Yes statement "dependencies has been loaded successfully" appeared. However no libraries linked.